# Link with a non-clickable background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu that is formatted as an unordered list where the **links** (instead of the list items) have a background images that look like bullets. Due to the complexity of the CSS, I am not able to change this - the background images have to "belong" to the links, not to the list items.

My issue is that I would like to be able to have the links direct me to their respective pages, while also having the background images work to expand subcategories. This means that I need to somehow "separate" the background image from the link in order to reference it separately in my jQuery animation.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#mainnav ul li").on("click", function(e) {
        var $t = $(e.target);
        if (!$t.is("a")) {
            $(this).children("ul").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

because right now I am just using this and it doesn't work when I actually want to click on the links:

```
$("#mainnav ul li").click(function () {
    $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

I've attached a demo (though keep in mind that this not my actual code, it is just an example of how I would like this to work): http://jsfiddle.net/stamblerre/GzD3M/11/

I would like to be able to click on JUST the pencils to expand the subcategories so that I can use the text to click on the link and be directed to another page. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this **without** associating the background-image with the list items rather than the links?

Thank you!!

---

With the help of many of the people on this thread, I've figured out my issue, here's the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/stamblerre/GzD3M/19/

Comment: Right now in the css the pencils are attached to the link. Since its not a separate div and it is attached to the link you cannot separate it from clicking on the link.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/GzD3M/12/ ??

Comment: @tsHunter there is a high chance that you downvoted my answer, feel free to explain. The solution works expectedly.

Comment: @King King. I did explain, no need to start a head hunt on me for a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the clicked point to see if it's in the icon's region, actually we can just check the horizontal coordinates. We know that you set `padding-left:15px` for the `a` element, which means the icon's width is about 15px. If the clicked point is in the icon's region, we will let the click event propagate, otherwise stop it from propagating.

```
$('#mainnav ul li > a').click(function(e){
    if(e.pageX - $(e.target).offset().left >= 15) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();            
    }
});
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/GzD3M/16/)

Comment: @stamblerre if you want the link to still function normally, just remove the `e.preventDefault()` (in my code). that's all. like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/GzD3M/20/ . However actually your demo is better.

Comment: it doesn't work because the pencils then also start linking. i think whatever i have in my final demo is the functionality i intended, but thank you

Comment: @stamblerre have you checked the demo in the previous comment, I did not mean removing the `e.preventDefault()`, in fact move it to the `else` statement.

Comment: ok thanks, that works fine. i think my solution also works similarly - thank you for your help, i think i'm good now.

Comment: All I can say here is Kudos to @stamblerre for trying to dig through the *noise* that I've deleted here.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your background-image into a pseudo element and use pointer-events so it doesn't catch the click.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GzD3M/13/)**

```
#mainnav a {
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#mainnav a:before {
    content: url(http://shapeshed.com/images/articles/pencil_icon.gif);
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right:5px;
    pointer-events:none;/* this is where it happens if browser understands it */
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#mainnav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#mainnav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i don't think it will work in my case because it involves modifying the way that the background-images are attached to the links (which unfortunately, i can't do). if i was able to do that, you're answer would be great (though a much easier way would have been to make the images the bullets...which is why this has been causing me so much trouble...). thanks though! your answer definitely taught me some more about CSS since i'm just starting :)

Comment: How do you set this background-image in real. class can be used and CSS rules or class redefined via jQuery if needed . Those rules here shows you a CSS method with the selector you provided. This selectors can be anything else and rules hold in classes

Answer (score 0):

just add next to the link another link with the pencil image inside with a unique class that will open the nested ul, something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="pencil"><img src="pencil.jpg"></a> <a href="any url">Click me</a>
        <ul style="display:none" class="nested_ul">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pencil').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().children(".nested_ul").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
    });
 });
```

it's 100% working!...good luck.